# Fitting a beta distribution to a probability density curve

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

If I have a spectral data set showing measured energy on the y-axis and frequency on the x-axis, how would I go about fitting this to a beta distribution?

For example, lets say I had the data for the following curves showing spectrum for this ship:

[image]

How do I determine the beta curve fit parameters to say the blue line?

Taking it one step further. If I have a wav sound file of the sound of an engine, how would I do the same thing?

***UPDATE***

I attempted to use the supplied answer and got an error as follows:

[image]

**The data file can be downloaded from the following URL: [acoustic power spectrum data to 3k hz](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=Tuq6zvba)**

The overall goal here is to generate a curve approximating the shape like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about fitting a Beta Distribution to this data? A Beta distribution has a finite support (0..1) which your data doesn't have and an interpretation related to probability, which I find hard to make in the context of frequency spectra of sounds.

Comment: What do you mean by finite support?

Comment: A beta distribution is defined only between 0 and 1.

Comment: I get the same answer if I scale the values so they are less than 1.

Comment: suggest you spend some time learning what a beta distribution is.  Do some plots and manually try to find some parameters that reasonably resemble your data.

Comment: @tyler I didn't mean vertically but horizontally. Anyway, for what reason would you want a distribution to a sound spectrum?

Comment: I want to find a way to approximate the shape of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=Tuq6zvba", "TEXT"];
data1 = Transpose[{Rest@Range[0, 1, 1./Length@#], #}] &@ ToExpression@StringSplit[data];
model = PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b], x];
parms = FindFit[data1, model, {a, b}, x]
Show[Graphics[Point@data1, Axes -> True], 
     Plot[model /. parms, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> All],
     AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tried to use this method and got an error about a "gradient" as shown above in the updated question.

Comment: @TylerDurden See Sjoerd's comments under your question

Comment: I get the same error if I scale the y-values to be less than 1 (see updated screenshot in question)

Comment: @TylerDurden Please post a sample of your data set. Otherwise your problem is impossible to debug

Comment: How do I post data (it is a .wav file that is about 1 megabyte in size)?

Comment: @TylerDurden Your question doesn't include sound processing. Share a list of values you want to fit with the distribution at any (no-registration-needed) data sharing site. Try to make the list as short as you can.

Comment: I have posted the data and added the URL to the question near the bottom. The file is about 50K in size.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you are interested in a general shape of your data. This can be inferred from the nature of your data, and most probably does not follow a beta distribution. You can use a polynomial series of a chosen degree to visualize a more general shape of your data:

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=Tuq6zvba", "TEXT"];
data1 = Transpose[{Rest@Range[0, 1, 1./Length@#], #}] &@
   ToExpression@StringSplit[data];
lp = ListLinePlot[MovingAverage[data1, 50]];

Clear[n, a, b, c, i, x, polynome, polyGauss]
polynome[n_] := 
 NonlinearModelFit[data1, Sum[a[i + 1]*x^i, {i, 0, n}], 
  Flatten[Table[{a[i + 1]}, {i, 0, n}]], x]

Show[{Plot[Evaluate[Table[polynome[n][x], {n, 3, 12, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick], lp}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: polynome fit]

Or you can use a series of Gaussian bell functions:

```
polyGauss[n_] := 
 NonlinearModelFit[data1, Sum[a[i]*Exp[-(b[i] x - c[i])^2], {i, n}], 
  Flatten[Table[{{a[i], 1}, {b[i], i/(n + 1)}, c[i]}, {i, n}], 1], x]

Show[{Plot[Evaluate[Table[polyGauss[n][x], {n, 3, 12, 3}]], {x, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick], lp}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: gaussian fit]